# Android WebView doesn't load data properly from HTML string

Tags: java, android, html, webview

I'm trying WebView to load data from an html string but it loads data as it is and does not convert it to a web view!

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_story);


        webView = findViewById(R.id.webView3);
        title = findViewById(R.id.title);

         String description = "&lt;p style=&quot;margin-bottom: 15px; padding: 0px; text-align: justify; font-size: 14px;&quot;&gt;Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla efficitur eros ut euismod feugiat. Duis efficitur, tortor non fermentum pulvinar, eros orci sodales nisi, ultrices eleifend enim enim id lacus. Phasellus vel commodo est. Sed nec mattis urna. Nunc non pretium nulla. Morbi pretium dolor leo, non tincidunt neque tristique quis. Nam molestie erat ac felis interdum convallis. Quisque quis justo tempor, faucibus sapien vitae, ornare quam. Phasellus imperdiet, dui vel dignissim porta, tortor massa blandit ante, eget imperdiet lectus ipsum ut turpis. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.&lt;\\/p&gt;&lt;p style=&quot;margin-bottom: 15px; padding: 0px; text-align: justify; font-size: 14px;&quot;&gt;Suspendisse finibus lorem quis est lobortis vehicula. Morbi non dolor finibus, volutpat dolor eget, feugiat lacus. Maecenas odio sapien, consectetur sit amet pretium id, semper in nisl. Vivamus molestie ex commodo turpis tristique, eget volutpat risus posuere. Integer ex nunc, sollicitudin in faucibus sed, facilisis non urna. In sed ultrices risus. Fusce sit amet neque accumsan, malesuada quam eu, venenatis ligula. Vestibulum ullamcorper lorem sit amet nibh pretium, sed faucibus nibh vulputate. Duis porttitor nisi in mi interdum, ac pharetra mi maximus. Mauris vulputate metus odio, quis mattis ex ornare in. Aliquam faucibus ultrices lectus a venenatis. Quisque fringilla interdum ex laoreet accumsan. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. In pretium faucibus lorem. Phasellus non ultrices purus. Phasellus pulvinar tristique mattis.&lt;\\/p&gt;&lt;p style=&quot;margin-bottom: 15px; padding: 0px; text-align: justify; font-size: 14px;&quot;&gt;Aliquam turpis ligula, tempus non dictum et, faucibus id nisl. Ut quis lorem sodales, molestie est et, facilisis elit. Donec sagittis, sapien a vestibulum placerat, turpis justo sollicitudin dolor, at pellentesque sapien ex ac nisl. Donec pretium odio a nunc bibendum malesuada. Nunc rhoncus, risus eu iaculis consequat, erat mi feugiat lorem, eget eleifend turpis libero quis sem. Donec tortor nisi, dictum sed velit quis, blandit tristique lectus. In consectetur fringilla imperdiet. Sed mattis sapien nibh, ac auctor dolor cursus eget. Vivamus cursus nec velit et vestibulum. Nunc laoreet fringilla consectetur. Sed sit amet diam in sem vestibulum placerat. Ut eu tristique diam.&lt;\\/p&gt;&lt;p style=&quot;margin-bottom: 15px; padding: 0px; text-align: justify; font-size: 14px;&quot;&gt;Suspendisse cursus et arcu sed feugiat. Nulla tempus id nulla a luctus. Cras consectetur lectus ut aliquet euismod. Morbi tincidunt iaculis lectus, vel volutpat diam fringilla rutrum. Morbi at enim eget massa maximus commodo. Morbi sagittis pellentesque rhoncus. Aenean sit amet volutpat purus, id tristique dolor. Sed eget fermentum velit. Vestibulum ultrices mi sed volutpat posuere. Morbi vehicula quam risus, at pulvinar urna tempus et. Sed nulla risus, congue vel pharetra vel, pulvinar eu felis. Duis rhoncus accumsan enim, non vestibulum justo mattis eget. Pellentesque lacus turpis, facilisis ullamcorper gravida a, eleifend non metus. Nullam sed orci at mauris bibendum tempor. Donec consequat nulla nec sem ullamcorper, sed tincidunt velit ullamcorper.&lt;\\/p&gt;&lt;p style=&quot;margin-bottom: 15px; padding: 0px; text-align: justify; font-size: 14px;&quot;&gt;Ut in aliquet erat. Vivamus pretium blandit sem, a aliquam lacus tincidunt ut. Ut ut lacinia diam, non maximus eros. Proin ipsum lacus, laoreet a felis sit amet, feugiat condimentum eros. Aenean iaculis enim non lacinia porttitor. Etiam in nibh ac nisl vehicula fringilla eu ac tellus. Proin sagittis magna vitae magna rutrum rhoncus. Fusce varius pharetra nulla, vel euismod orci malesuada id. Suspendisse potenti. Ut eu egestas est. Nam condimentum consequat massa sed rutrum. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Aliquam posuere nulla in urna efficitur, nec pharetra ex feugiat. Sed lorem libero, iaculis ut elit et, placerat hendrerit lectus. Morbi efficitur diam ut erat dapibus porta quis vitae lectus.&lt;\\/p&gt;";

        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.loadDataWithBaseURL("", description, "text/html", "UTF-8","");


    }
```

the output is just a text with the same html tags in the string.. I don't know what is the problem

Comment: You need to convert the entities into actual characters. Your content will not work in a regular Web browser either -- save the text to a file and load it in your desktop browser. `&lt;` needs to become `<` and `&gt;` needs to become `>`.

Comment: @CommonsWare Thanks, I replaced them programmatically and it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
&lt;p style=&quot;margin-bottom: 15px; padding: 0px; text-align: justify; font-size: 14px;&quot;&gt;Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla efficitur eros ut euismod feugiat. Duis efficitur, tortor non fermentum pulvinar, eros orci sodales nisi, ultrices eleifend enim enim id lacus. Phasellus vel commodo est. Sed nec mattis urna. Nunc non pretium nulla. Morbi pretium dolor leo, non tincidunt neque tristique quis. Nam molestie erat ac felis interdum convallis. Quisque quis justo tempor, faucibus sapien vitae, ornare quam. Phasellus imperdiet, dui vel dignissim porta, tortor massa blandit ante, eget imperdiet lectus ipsum ut turpis. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.&lt;\\/p&gt;&lt;p style=&quot;margin-bottom: 15px; padding: 0px; text-align: justify; font-size: 14px;&quot;&gt;Suspendisse finibus lorem quis est lobortis vehicula. Morbi non dolor finibus, volutpat dolor eget, feugiat lacus. Maecenas odio sapien, consectetur sit amet pretium id, semper in nisl. Vivamus molestie ex commodo turpis tristique, eget volutpat risus posuere. Integer ex nunc, sollicitudin in faucibus sed, facilisis non urna. In sed ultrices risus. Fusce sit amet neque accumsan, malesuada quam eu, venenatis ligula. Vestibulum ullamcorper lorem sit amet nibh pretium, sed faucibus nibh vulputate. Duis porttitor nisi in mi interdum, ac pharetra mi maximus. Mauris vulputate metus odio, quis mattis ex ornare in. Aliquam faucibus ultrices lectus a venenatis. Quisque fringilla interdum ex laoreet accumsan. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. In pretium faucibus lorem. Phasellus non ultrices purus. Phasellus pulvinar tristique mattis.&lt;\\/p&gt;&lt;p style=&quot;margin-bottom: 15px; padding: 0px; text-align: justify; font-size: 14px;&quot;&gt;Aliquam turpis ligula, tempus non dictum et, faucibus id nisl. Ut quis lorem sodales, molestie est et, facilisis elit. Donec sagittis, sapien a vestibulum placerat, turpis justo sollicitudin dolor, at pellentesque sapien ex ac nisl. Donec pretium odio a nunc bibendum malesuada. Nunc rhoncus, risus eu iaculis consequat, erat mi feugiat lorem, eget eleifend turpis libero quis sem. Donec tortor nisi, dictum sed velit quis, blandit tristique lectus. In consectetur fringilla imperdiet. Sed mattis sapien nibh, ac auctor dolor cursus eget. Vivamus cursus nec velit et vestibulum. Nunc laoreet fringilla consectetur. Sed sit amet diam in sem vestibulum placerat. Ut eu tristique diam.&lt;\\/p&gt;&lt;p style=&quot;margin-bottom: 15px; padding: 0px; text-align: justify; font-size: 14px;&quot;&gt;Suspendisse cursus et arcu sed feugiat. Nulla tempus id nulla a luctus. Cras consectetur lectus ut aliquet euismod. Morbi tincidunt iaculis lectus, vel volutpat diam fringilla rutrum. Morbi at enim eget massa maximus commodo. Morbi sagittis pellentesque rhoncus. Aenean sit amet volutpat purus, id tristique dolor. Sed eget fermentum velit. Vestibulum ultrices mi sed volutpat posuere. Morbi vehicula quam risus, at pulvinar urna tempus et. Sed nulla risus, congue vel pharetra vel, pulvinar eu felis. Duis rhoncus accumsan enim, non vestibulum justo mattis eget. Pellentesque lacus turpis, facilisis ullamcorper gravida a, eleifend non metus. Nullam sed orci at mauris bibendum tempor. Donec consequat nulla nec sem ullamcorper, sed tincidunt velit ullamcorper.&lt;\\/p&gt;&lt;p style=&quot;margin-bottom: 15px; padding: 0px; text-align: justify; font-size: 14px;&quot;&gt;Ut in aliquet erat. Vivamus pretium blandit sem, a aliquam lacus tincidunt ut. Ut ut lacinia diam, non maximus eros. Proin ipsum lacus, laoreet a felis sit amet, feugiat condimentum eros. Aenean iaculis enim non lacinia porttitor. Etiam in nibh ac nisl vehicula fringilla eu ac tellus. Proin sagittis magna vitae magna rutrum rhoncus. Fusce varius pharetra nulla, vel euismod orci malesuada id. Suspendisse potenti. Ut eu egestas est. Nam condimentum consequat massa sed rutrum. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Aliquam posuere nulla in urna efficitur, nec pharetra ex feugiat. Sed lorem libero, iaculis ut elit et, placerat hendrerit lectus. Morbi efficitur diam ut erat dapibus porta quis vitae lectus.&lt;\\/p&gt;
```

That is not valid HTML. It has been entity-escaped. You need to replace `&lt;` with `<` and `&gt;` with `>`.